# How to insert dashed line after line break google script (docs)

Tags: google-apps-script

In google docs I need to insert a dashed line as soon as a line break is detected and it needs to fill the entire line

eg:
hello----------------------

Im new in google script and by the moment i have accomplish to find the line break but instead of adding a dash im replacing the whole line with a dash:

```
 function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText("[^\n]+", "-"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get all the paragraphs, iterate over each one of them and replace `the existing text` with `the existing text + -----------`:

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
  for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
    if ( body[i].getText() != '') {
      body[i].editAsText().replaceText(body[i].getText(),body[i].getText() + "---------------")
    }
  }
}
```

So you will no be searching for a break line but instead you add it to the end of the paragraph, every paragraph is set from a break line, so this will work for you.

Comment: Hi @Kessy. Nice, is working as long there are not empty lines, then I get an Invalid argument on searchPattern it must by due to an empty string, luckily documents being used with this script don't have empty lines. how can we do to count remaining characters in a line so we can fill the whole line with dashes instead of just adding a fix amount.

Comment: Answer edited, just added an if to check if the paragraph is empty.